# importing one function to another

Tags: python

I am importing the `fun.py` module into the `chr_cnt` function. The `cnt_list` function takes a list as argument. When I call this function in `chr_cnt` function using `import`, I am not sure how to pass an argument for the `chr_cnt` function to the `cnt_list` function.

My `fun.py` module:

```
def cnt_list(li):
    my_dict = {}
    for i in li:
        if i in my_dict:
            my_dict[i] = my_dict[i]+1
        else:
            my_dict[i] = 1
    return my_dict
    # print cnt_list([1,2,3,3,1])
```

My script:

```
import fun
def chr_cnt(s):
    res={}
    res=fun.cnt_list(s) # or res=fun.cnt_list(list(s))
    return res

print chr_cnt("aabbc")
```

expected result:

```
{'a':2, 'b':2,'c':1}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the question.

Comment: Your code already works, as posted. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The last line `print chr_cnt("aabbc")` should not be indented; right now it's in the scope of the function.

Comment: You can do either `cnt_list(s)` or `cnt_list(list(s))`. The latter will explicitly transform the string into a list, but you can just as well loop over the string `s` directly (which the first variant would do).

Comment: Note that my editing may have inadvertently fixed the issue (`print chr_cnt("aabbc")` was originally badly indented as if it was part of the `chr_cnt()` function). If so, this question was nothing but a typographical problem.

Comment: I am very new to python. Just started learning.  I think my indentation was not correct.

Comment: and thanks all for prompt response.

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me? Are you sure you have the right indenting? I've made it a bit shorter for you:
fun.py:

```
def cnt_list(li):
  my_dict = {}
  for i in li:
    if i in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] = my_dict[i]+1
    else:
        my_dict[i] = 1
  return my_dict
```

main.py:

```
import fun
def chr_cnt(s):
  return fun.cnt_list(s)

print chr_cnt("aabbc")
```